# SSL - subjectaltname vs. commercial

Tags: ssl

I'm reading about how to install SSL in the linode.com library.   Why would one choose the [commercial approach](http://library.linode.com/ssl-guides/commercial-ssl-cert) over the [subjectaltname approach](http://library.linode.com/ssl-guides/subject-alt-name-ssl)?  The subjectaltname approach allows the flexibility to host multiple secure DNS while the commercial approach does not.  So why not just stick with the subjectaltname approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple sites to secure on one server, using SubjectAltNames (with a SAN or [UC SSL certificate](http://www.sslshopper.com/unified-communications-uc-ssl-certificates.html)) is a great solution. It is slightly more secure to use separate certificates for each site, but the difference is negligible in most cases.

Comment: Sometimes in Firefox, I get a warning message about an SSL and it asks me to make an exception before proceeding.  Do you know if issues of this nature will exist with the subjectaltname approach?

Comment: No, they won't exist.